# RestControllerAdvide does not help to return desired model

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the `ControllerAdvice` like this

```java
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ErrorHandlingControllerAdvice {

    .....

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler({ HttpMessageNotWritableException.class })
    public @ResponseBody ApiError handleMessageNotWritableException(HttpMessageNotWritableException ex, WebRequest request) {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletWebRequest)request).getRequest();
        log.warn("Invalid message format: API: {}", httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
        return new ApiError(ApiCode.MESSAGE_FORMAT, getMessage(ApiCode.MESSAGE_FORMAT, ex));
    }
    .....

}
```

Also, I have the following custom Jackson double deserializer

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomDoubleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> {

    private final int precision;

    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(DoubleUtils.convertWithPrecision(value, precision));
    }

}
```

If the double value is `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, I catch the `HttpMessageNotWritableException` in the `controllerAdvice`. All is OK.
But the client does not get the error from `controllerAdvice`. It gets the request body + model from the controller advice.

It looks like the following:

```json
{"i":0,"ii":null,"s":null,"l":0,"ll":null,"c":"\u0000","cc":null,"d"}{"code":"MESSAGE_FORMAT","message":"Internal system error"}
```

How can I solve this problem for getting only the correct message?